# How to add JSON support with XML already working?

Tags: java, xml, json, spring, spring-mvc

How is JSON support added to dispatch-servlet.xml (XML is working without problems)?
Commented text was just fail attempt...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.example.domain"/>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
                </beans:bean>
<!--                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
                </beans:bean> -->
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>

    <beans:bean name="note" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
    </beans:bean>   
<!--    <beans:bean name="note" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
</beans:bean> -->   

    <!-- InternalResourceViewResolver should be the last sice it always returns/resolves a view -->
    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass"  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Additional solution, for:
    `method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=application/json"` 

You still need:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter>
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

To correctly bind java object for **@RequestBody**.

Comment: Wow, what's with the down votes? At least leave me some pointers...

Comment: Wasn't a downvoter, but I would imagine it was for not telling us *how* the failed attempt failed and what the errors were :)

Comment: Ok, I agree, I could go more in details... AHungerArtist's answer helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
       <property name="objectMapper">
            <ref bean="JacksonObjectMapper" />
       </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <property name="objectMapper">
         <ref bean="JacksonObjectMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="JacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
```

It doesn't make sense that you would use the JaxB marshaller to instantiate Jackson (I don't think).

An example of using ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <ref bean="JacksonObjectMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <property name="marshaller">
                    <ref bean="Jaxb2Marshaller" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
    <property name="useNotAcceptableStatusCode" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You got it, but works if I leave XML beans out. Could you advise how to use this in combination with XML and with the same "<beans:bean name="note"" for BeanNameViewResolver?

Comment: What version of Spring are you working with? And how/where are you using note?

Comment: If you are able to use the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, it seems like that would be pretty easy to pop in and use.

Comment: I added an example of using the CNVR to my OP. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found on here that you may need to update your version of your jackson-asl jar http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=83954

Try looking at that and see if upgrading it fixes the problem.

Comment: If this is Glassfish only ... I use Jetty and also tried adding jackson-all-1.6.2.jar with the same error. AHungerArtist got it.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for updating my post so I can see the answer :-)